# int object is unscriptable Python

Tags: python, list, error-handling

I'm trying to make Battleship for practice, and single player was a success...when there was only one player and one set of ships and a board :P

Any idea why this is giving me an 'int object is unscriptable' error???

Here is the Board class. Well, some of it anyway:

```
class Board:
    'Game Board'
    topMarkers = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    sideMarkers = list(range(0, 26))


    def __init__(self,h,w): #Makes the map
        self.height = h
        self.width = w

        self.xMarkers = []
        self.yMarkers = []
        self.hitList = []
        self.hitListCopy = []

        self.boardSpace = '         '

        wave = '~'
        self.row = []
        self.column = []
        #self.column = wave * self.width # If width is 4, column is now '~~~~'

        for c in range(self.width):
            self.column.append(wave)
            self.xMarkers.append(Board.topMarkers[c])

        for r in range(self.height): #
            self.row.append(self.column[:]) #Use the slice to make copies
            self.yMarkers.append(Board.sideMarkers[r])



    def showGrid(self):
        print self.boardSpace + '  ' +  ' '.join(self.xMarkers)
        for i in range(self.height):
            print self.boardSpace + str(self.yMarkers[i]) + ' ' + '-'.join(self.row[i])
```

And here's the code that actually runs it, the part of the code that is causing it is in the bottom while and for loop, where it says in the comment to show the grid of YOUR map.

```
p1 = [[Board(7,7), Board(7,7)], Move(), Connection(1, netEnable)]
p2 = [[Board(7,7), Board(7,7)], Move(), Connection(2, netEnable)]
#p3 = [[Board(7,7), Board(7,7)], Move(), Connection(3, netEnable)]

#Like this p1 = [[theirBoard, attackBoard], Moves, Connection]



#p = [p1,p2,p3]
p = [p1,p2]


ships = [Ship(0),Ship(0),Ship(0)]
ships2 = [Ship(0),Ship(0),Ship(0)]

numOfPlayers = len(p)


youPlayer = int(raw_input('Which player are you? 1,2,3:   '))

youPlayer -= 1



boardr = p[youPlayer][0][1].getRowData()
boardM = p[youPlayer][0][0].getMarkerData()
#raw_input(boardr)
raw_input(boardM)



#Set Ships Dialog.
for i in range(len(ships)):
    p[youPlayer][0][1].showGrid() 
    ships[i].setShip(boardr, boardM)


shipPosAll = [[],[],[]]    

for i in range(len(ships)):
    shipPosAll[youPlayer].append(ships[i].getShip()) #USE THIS INFO TO FEED TO THE BOARD TO TELL IT WHERE SHIPS ARE SO YOU KNOW WHERE HITS ARE.

print 'shipPos at line 382 : %s' % (shipPosAll[youPlayer])




#INIT, DO ONLY ONCE

for i in range(numOfPlayers): 
    print p[i][2].GetTime()

#MAIN LOOP
while gameNotOver:

    for i in range(numOfPlayers):
        playersCheck = [0,1]
        del playersCheck[youPlayer]

        print 'Player %s turn' % (i)
        print 'Here are your ships'
        #raw_input (p[i][0][1])
        p[i][0][1].showGrid() #Show the grid of the player (TheirShips) HERES WHERE THE PROBLEM IS!!!!

        print 'Where do you want to attack?'
        p[i][0][0].showGrid() #Show the grid of the player (AttackShips)

        hits = p[i][0][0].getHitList()
        alreadyMade = False
        while alreadyMade == False:
            coords = p[i][0][0].chooseMove()
            alreadyMade = p[i][1].addMove(coords) #Returns true if move accepted, otherwise false

        lastMove = p[i][1].getMove()
        print 'The move you made was %s' % (lastMove)
        p[i][2].Send(lastMove)
        changeCoords = p[i][2].Check()
        p[i][0][0].changeRow('B')

        for p in playersCheck: #Check every player who is not you. You were deleted at teh beginning.
            checkForSunk(shipPosAll[p], hits)
            print 'Current Attacked Players shipPos: %s' % (shipPosAll[p])
        #p1Site.Send(coords)
        #print 'Thing %s' % (shipPos[i])
            if isGameOver(shipPosAll[p]): #PROBLEM.
                gameNotOver = False
                break

    for i in range(numOfPlayers):
        print p[i][1].getAllMoves()


print 'All Ships Sunk. The End. Wat more you want from mme its 3:48am'
```

Thanks

Here's the exact message I get.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "name/battleship_wClasses.py",
>   line 431, in  p[i][0][1].showGrid() #Show the grid of the
>   player (TheirShips) TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable –

Comment: Please post the exact error message, including line number.

Comment: Wow this is a LOT of code, can you please provide the full trace-back along with a comment in the code identifying the problem line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name/battleship_wClasses.py", line 431, in <module>
    p[i][0][1].showGrid() #Show the grid of the player (TheirShips)
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: And this isn't even the full code...all for a terminal battleship game...that I took a week off from and now forget how it works :P....anyway, there is a comment in the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two (overlapping) contradictory definitions for `p`:

```
p = [p1,p2]
```

and

```
    playersCheck = [0,1]
    for p in playersCheck:
```

`p[i][0][1].showGrid()` works with the first definition, but fails when `p` is assigned an integer value from the second definition.

Comment: Oh WOW this is the first time a for loop has actually interfered with a variable...I was always under the assumption that for loop iteration vars only exist during the loop. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is a Python pitfall -- `for-loops` "leak" their iterating variable into the surrounding scope.